# Ratchet Fatal Error: Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found in C:\wamp\www\bin\chat-server.php

Tags: php, html5, websocket, chat

Estou tentando aprender como utilizar a nova API do Html5, o WebSocket, e resolvi começar testando o Ratchet, que é uma biblioteca php. Enfim, segui todos os passos desse tutorial para a criação de um chat básico http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world e ao executar no terminal ele não encontra a classe Chat.php. Já troquei essa classe de lugar várias vezes e nada faz funcionar. A estrutura dos arquivos está assim:

```
bin
   chat-server.php
src
   MyApp
      Chat.php
vendor
   autoload.php
   (...)
composer.json
composer.lock
```

Os meu arquivos estão assim:

**composer.json**

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MyApp": "src"
    }
 },
 "require": {
    "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*"
 }
}
```

**chat-server.php**

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

**Chat.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

ps: Encontrei em fóruns algumas questões parecidas, mas nenhum procedimento resolveu

Comment: Instalou as dependências do pacote? `composer install`. Caso não, recomendo começar lendo isso aqui: http://br.phptherightway.com/

Comment: sim, eu instalei, desinstalei e instalei de novo pra garantir e nada

Answer (score 1):

Estive com o mesmo problema, mas consegui resolver da seguinte forma, após fazer tudo isso que você fez, entre novamente na pasta do seu projeto via terminal e execute: `composer update` após isso rode o servidor com o comando também no terminal `php bin/chat-server.php`

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADA ! Eu tinha até desistido, mas a sua resposta me ajudou e fez funcionar, muito obrigada mesmo